# neo4j GraSS upload removes property quotes

Tags: neo4j, grass-file

I've downloaded the graphstyle.grass and added the following property to the pre-existing label:

```
node.CELL {
  color: '{color}';
  border-color: #60B58B;
  text-color-internal: #FFFFFF;
  caption: '{idx}';
}
```

(The `color` property used to be `#6DCE9E`)

But now, after uploading that new GraSS file to the neo4j browser, all `CELL`-nodes are black. When I examine the GraSS file on the browser, it is now:

```
node.CELL {
  color: {color};
  border-color: #60B58B;
  text-color-internal: #FFFFFF;
  caption: '{idx}';
}
```

1) Why did neo4j remove my quotes around the `{color}`-reference?
2) How can I write the GraSS file so that neo4j recognizes that the color is derived from the `color`-property of the `CELL` nodes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The neo4j browser does not support setting colors from node/relationship properties.

Aside from the neo4j browser, there are a number of other [visualization tools for neo4j](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/#_library_alchemy_js_open_source_graph_visualization). Perfhaps one of them will work better for you.